# Can I create a native windows desktop application using Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows, winapi

So I have heard of http://appjs.com/ and http://electron.atom.io/, but what I want to know can I create a native application using node.js?

From my understanding any language can call WINAPI, and it is possible due to that it's just a question if somebody is willing to create a wrapper for them? ( And possibly create equivalents in Linux / OSX )

I just want to know if my understanding is correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do node.js and desktop apps relate?

Comment: It's more of a understanding how things work than a node.js question, I just want to know if it is possible, I'm not saying that it should be done?

Comment: You want to call winapi from javascript? Where does node come into it?

Comment: Every programming language that can consume a C interface is capable of producing a 'native' Windows application. You are probably being down-voted, because the question is almost like asking: Which programming language is more Turing-complete?

Comment: What does it mean to consume a C interface? Thanks!

Comment: To consume a C interface means, to call into a C function and be able to receive the return value(s). I don't know of a single programming language (experimental ones, like Brainfuck, aside), that cannot call C functions. So yes, probably any language can call the Windows API (including those services exposed through [COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363.aspx)).

Comment: The downvotes are probably because this is a pure research question which implies you haven't done the research. Try Googling "win32 api node" or something to that effect. I know for a fact Node.js can call C code, so this is definitely possible.

Comment: Yeah I googled win32 api node but I never before thought that any language can do it, that's when I googled those stuff I had to be sure.

Thanks for the explanation @IInspectable, very much appreciated!

Submit an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there are already modules that do this by interfacing with the Windows API.

You can try [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) as well, a module for loading DLLs.